# Can あります be used to say: "I have to do X on a certain day"?

Tags: grammar, usage, verbs

From what I've read あります can be used to say "There is/There are X nonliving things.  あります Can also be used to say one has something. I'm wondering if it can be used like this:

> わたし は すいようび に アルバイト が あります

My goal of in making this sentence was to say

> I have a part-time job on Wednesday

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to say this though hence the question.  The original version of the sentence did not have わたし は in it but I added it since I'm not sure if the sentence would make sense without it. If anyone can let me know whether or not this is the correct way to say that I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence

> 私{わたし}は水曜日{すいようび}にアルバイトがあります。

is absolutely correct sentence to say

> I have a part-time job on Wednesday.

(or "I have to do a part-time job on Wednesday").

You can choose whether adding わたしは to the sentence or not.
Both sentences make sense and natural sentences for me.

「水曜日{すいようび}にアルバイトがあります。」 is, if anything, preferable because わたし is often clear in most of the situation and Japanese people tend to omit an obvious subject, but both sentences are used in general.